# How to get a list of keys matching a subset of their values-list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined some triangles and their centroid-coordinates, as well as the indices of their vertices and put all this together in a dicctionary, where the general order is:`{'triangle_id': centroid-coordinates(x,y,z), [list of vertices]}`. So filled with some examplary numbers:

```
test_dict = {'1': [15.3, 9.1, 0.0, [1, 2, 3]], '2': [20.1, 10.3, 5.0, [2, 3, 4]], '3': [19.7, 0.0, 20.9, [2, 7, 8]]}
```

Now I try to get a list of all keys which contain a value of the nested value-list, e.g.

```
# value to match: val = 3
['1', '2']
```

So far I tried the examples from [this tutorial](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-find-keys-by-value-in-dictionary/) and also [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-key-from-python-dictionary-using-value-2b2f8dd2a995). But it doesn't find anything. all I get is either an error, telling me that the value does not exist, or nothing.
I've tried to access the specific value-part by subscripting the `test_dict.values()[3]` but that's not working, as `test_dict.values()` is not subscriptable (also tried `test_dict.values[3]())` same result).

Is it possible to access the nested list of points from my values-list? Or do I have to put these vertices as simple entries into the value list for my dictionary?

I get these vertices already as a list from another function, that's why I put them here in the dictionary this way.

Comment: Try changing `dict.values()[3]` to `[*dict.values()][3-1]`

Comment: Still says it is not subsciptable. My IDE says: <<Class 'ValuesView' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances>>. What stands the '[3-1]' part for? never saw that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of a very ugly way to solve that problem.
You could write a function, and create some lists.
One list to store the keys, one to store the sublist of the values.
create a new dictionary with same keys, but only the sublists as values,

At the end check if the value occurs in one of the keys values, if yes, append the key to a new list, when done iterating, return the result list.

This should work:

```
def dummy(d,k):
    only_sub = []
    key_list = list(d.keys())
    new_d = {}
    res = []


    for item in list(d.values()):
        for sublist in item:
            if type(sublist) == list:
                only_sub.append(sublist)

    for i,j in zip(key_list,only_sub):
        new_d|={i:j}

    for item in only_sub:
        if k in item:
            res.append(key_list[only_sub.index(item)])
    
    return res


print(dummy({'1': [15.3, 9.1, 0.0, [1, 2, 3]],
 '2': [20.1, 10.3, 5.0, [2, 3, 4]], '3': [19.7, 0.0, 20.9, [2, 7, 8]]},3))
```

note: `new_d |= {i:j}` will only work in python 3.9 if i remember correctly.

In other versions rewrite that line to `new_d[i]=j`

Comment: So, I tried that (atm using Python 3.7.9, cannot use 3.9 as the proprietary software I'm working with isn't compatible to that point). So I tried it with the outdated variant of `new_d.update({i: j})`, which leads to an empty list or, to 'set()' as output. I know, dictionaries aren't meant for that, but since the software don't accept pandas I can't work with DataFrames, what would be my first attempt.

Comment: @Grinnorye try and rewrite it to: ```new_d[i]=j``` and i strongly recommend you to run the code through: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit , so you understand what happens.

Comment: Okay, now it's working. Thank you very much for your help and the recommendation of pythontutor.com never heard about this site but will definitly use it in future.

Answer (score 1):

try it...

```
test_dict = {'1': [15.3, 9.1, 0.0, [1, 2, 3]], '2': [20.1, 10.3, 5.0, [2, 3, 4]], '3': [19.7, 0.0, 20.9, [2, 7, 8]]}
val = input('Enter Value : ')
keys = {k:[a for a in v[3] if a == int(val)] for k,v in test_dict.items()}
keyss = {k:v for k,v in keys.items() if v}
result = [i for i in keyss.keys()]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the line `dict.values()[3]`

The key in `dict.values()[3]` should be `dict['3']`

And also don't use dict as a variable. Because it is an in-built keyword

Comment: With a string as list index i get: _TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str_.

Comment: maybe it should be `dict['3']` because `dict.values` is a list

Comment: Then I'll get the values for key '3'.