# Alternatives of zip to create dictionaries from lists in python 3.7

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have some lists and try to combine them to a dictionary. Using `zip()` worked fine I thought. But while working more with my created dictionary I came to the conclusion, that the tuples returned from `zip()` are a real problem. Problem in this case means that using the code from [this answer on my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819613/15175594) creates just an empty list. The complete code so far can be seen and tested [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=faceid%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%0Aface_x%20%3D%20%5B15.4,%2020.7,%2019.3%5D%0Aface_y%20%3D%20%5B9.2,%2010.6,%200.0%5D%0Aface_z%20%3D%20%5B0.1,%205.5,%2020.4%5D%0Avertices%20%3D%20%5B%5B1,%202,%203%5D,%20%5B2,%203,%204%5D,%20%5B2,%207,%208%5D%5D%0A%0Aface_and_nodes%20%3D%20%5Bfaceid,%20face_x,%20face_y,%20face_z,%20vertices%5D%0Alist_of_values%20%3D%20%5Bface_x,%20face_y,%20face_z,%20vertices%5D%0A%0Aface_nodes_dict%20%3D%20%7Bz%5B0%5D%3A%20%5Bz%5B1%3A%5D%5D%20for%20z%20in%20zip%28*face_and_nodes%29%7D%0A%0Adef%20dummy%28d,%20k%29%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20only_sub%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20key_list%20%3D%20list%28d.keys%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20new_d%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20item%20in%20list%28d.values%28%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20sublist%20in%20item%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20type%28sublist%29%20%3D%3D%20list%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20only_sub.append%28sublist%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i,%20j%20in%20zip%28key_list,%20only_sub%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new_d%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20j%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20item%20in%20only_sub%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20k%20in%20item%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res.append%28key_list%5Bonly_sub.index%28item%29%5D%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20res%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28dummy%28face_nodes_dict,%20k%3D3%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

My lists look like:

```
faceid = [1, 2, 3]
face_x = [15.4, 20.7, 19.3]
face_y = [9.2, 10.6, 0.0]
face_z = [0.1, 5.5, 20.4]
vertices = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 7, 8]]
```

And the dictionary creation using zip like:

```
face_and_nodes = [faceid, face_x, face_y, face_z, vertices]
face_nodes_dict = {z[0]: [z[1:]] for z in zip(*face_and_nodes)}
print("face_node_dict: ", face_nodes_dict, sep="\n")
```

This leads to the current output:

`face_node_dict`:

```
{1: [(15.4, 9.2, 0.1, [1, 2, 3])], 2: [(20.7, 10.6, 5.5, [2, 3, 4])], 3: [(19.3, 0.0, 20.4, [2, 7, 8])]}
```

What I need is something like:

`face_node_dict_correct`:

```
{1: [15.4, 9.2, 0.1, [1, 2, 3]], 2: [20.7, 10.6, 5.5, [2, 3, 4]], 3: [19.3, 0.0, 20.4, [2, 7, 8]]}
```

I would write the dictionary by hand, but it has to be done for some thousand entries, so that's not an option.

The question is now: How can I create my dictionary without having issues with tuples from zip, or is there any alternative which would suits my problem better?

Since I was looking for a solution the past hours, I really hope someone has an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean?:

```py
face_nodes_dict = {z[0]: list(z[1:]) for z in zip(*face_and_nodes)}
print(face_nodes_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: [15.4, 9.2, 0.1, [1, 2, 3]], 
 2: [20.7, 10.6, 5.5, [2, 3, 4]], 
 3: [19.3, 0.0, 20.4, [2, 7, 8]]}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for..Wow, now I'm feeling a bit dump. Thought using [z[1:]] would produce the same as using list(z[1:]).

Comment: @Grinnorye No, `[value]` and `list(value)` are different. That's common mistake. First produces list with one `value` and second iterates over `value` creating a list.